# Объединение и вывод сортированного запроса

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, yii

- Есть более двух таблиц в которых одинаковое количество полей.
- Мне нужно сделать выборку всех данных, отсортировать и вывести в том порядке котором мне нужно, допустим по дате.
- База данных `Postgresql`
- Данные должны выводится так как будто они находятся в одной таблице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно получится так как на картинке с сортировкой по дате

Нашел причину почему не работает так как нужно, теперь не знаю как это исправить, код написан на Yii2

```
$query = new Query();
 $query2 = new Query();

 $query->from(HistoryRefill::tableName());
 $query2->from(HistorySend::tableName());

 $result = $query->union($query2)->orderBy('created_at')->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

Выдает такой результат

> ```
> (SELECT * FROM "history_refill" ORDER BY "created_at") UNION ( SELECT * FROM "history_send" )
> ```

а должно быть так

> SELECT * FROM "history_refill" UNION SELECT
>   * FROM "history_send" ORDER BY "created_at"

Yii при формировании запроса сам ставит скобки, можно конечно использовать  `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()` но тогда не будет работать `ActiveDataProvider`
Как выйти из ситуации?

Comment: какую часть из вышеперечисленного вы не знаете как сделать? в чем сложность?

Comment: @teran если UNION мне бы помог я бы сюда не писал, UNION не делает то что я написал выше он соединяет данные и выводит их одной таблицей, а мне нужно взять два больших списка перемешать их и вывести отсортированым по дате!

Comment: Из описанной вами задачи, `union` это то что вам надо. Поэтому, вы либо не смогли его правильно использовать, применяя сортировку после объединения. Либо вы не смогли корректно описать вашу задачу. И скорее всего  тут первое.

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос ([edit]) и добавьте примеры данных таблиц и желаемого результата.

Comment: @teran подправил

Comment: @Ricco381 по-вашему картинки с червячками - это примеры данных?

Comment: Напишите пример вашего запроса, как вы пробовали с `UNION` и у вас не получилось. К гадалке не ходи - в конце запроса отсутствует `ORDER BY dateFieldName`

Comment: @teran отредактировал

Comment: @DmitriySimushev а вам не все равно какие у меня данные, вывод любых данных происходит одинаково, и да, у меня данные могут состоять из червяков, или это запрещено?

Comment: @Ricco381, кому нужен ответ: вам или мне? ;)

Answer (score 2):

> а должно быть так
>
> > SELECT * FROM "history_refill" UNION SELECT * FROM "history_send" ORDER BY "created_at"

Не должно.

Раз уж вы используете Yii, то вам подойдет только вариант с оборачивающим запросом:

```
$query1 = (new Query())
    ->select('foo, bar')
    ->from('foo');

$query2 = (new Query())
    ->select('foo, bar')
    ->from('bar');

(new Query())
    ->select('*')
    ->from($query1->union($query2))
    ->orderBy('foo');
```

Вот такой SQL код должен получится на выходе:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT foo, bar FROM foo) UNION (SELECT foo, bar FROM bar)
) ORDER BY foo
```

Comment: Так не работает PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given ошибка в том что передать sql в метод from наверно нельзя